# How to i can use return PHP variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to pass variables from an If - Else structure in PHP to AngularJS script. I can't use the PHP File $message variable in AngularJS.

Update PHP

```
$db = new connect();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$ID = $data->id;
$result = $db->select("persons","id= ".$ID."");

if ($result == null){
$message = "Error!"; // I can't use in AngularJS
}
else{
$NewPassword = md5($ID);
$runupdate = $db->update("persons",array("password"=>$NewPassword),"id",$ID);
$message = "Success!"; // I can't use in AngularJS
}
echo json_encode($message);
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http, $interval){ 
$scope.Update = function (id) {
$http.post('update.php',{'id' : id}).then(function (data, status, headers, config)
{     
$scope.resultmessage = data.message;  // Thats not working
});
}
});
```

Index PHP

```
<a ng-if="resultmessage == 'Error!' ">{{resultmessage}}</a>
<a ng-if="resultmessage == 'Success!' ">{{resultmessage}}</a>
```

It does update if I don't use if-else in PHP. But I want to publish a message as a result of the update.

Comment: The signature for the `.then` method is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient. In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. A question needs a full description of the problem before a solution can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic thing.

in php

```
$php_variable = "send me to angularjs controller";
```

in AngularJs controller.

```
$scope.resultmessage = <?= $php_variable; ?>; //equivalent to <?php echo $php_variable;?>
```

you might need to account for the closing semicolon ; of javascript.
if its empty, set it to "";

in your case.

//initialize message

```
$message =array();
if ($result == null){
    $message["message"] = "Error";
}
else{
    //do your db stuff. then
    $message["message"] = "Success!";
}
echo json_encode($message);// outputs {"message":"Error!"}
```

AngularJS

```
$http.post('update.php',{'id' : id}).then(function (data, status, headers, config){     
    $scope.resultmessage = data.message;  // Thats should work
    //for the actual message
    data.message.message or may just be data.message;
});
```

to output json you want to format your result as json 
that's why i used an associative array with key value pairs. 
doing json_encode on a single string value wont work.